# Is the correct application page being displayed for create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

hello I am not sure if this is a bug, but I need to confirm two things. I can access my app through the localhost link which is http://localhost:3000 and http:192.168.1.69.3000.

[image: Local and network links]

however I get two different pages. on the localhost link I see a progressive web apps template page

[image: Progressive Web Apps]

and on the other link i see the react app example page with the spinning react logo.

[image: Spinning logo]

Is this the correct behaviour of create-react-app?

Many thanks.

Comment: On the window that shows the PWA template, can you Inspect -> Application -> Service Workers and unregister any service workers that are registered there? See if that fixes it.

Comment: @twharmon Yes that seems to work. I assume that the service worker is registered by default or was it just in my instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the window that shows the PWA template, go to Inspect -> Application -> Service Workers and unregister any service workers that are registered there.

This happened because you have previously registered a service worker at localhost:3000 that cached assets for a previous app.